# Parity - flush or ban peers

Tags: parity, peers

I am running a Parity node and I have a very odd problem with transmitting some transactions. My node appears to be working fine, but when I attempt to get some basic information from the blockchain like gas prices, it inconsistently returns. This is not an issue for a similar node I run in a different geo, and my node itself is happily returning absurd things like `undefined` for fees on a specific transaction I'm sending.

With no errors, the only thing I can think of is that the peers I'm connected to are crappy. Is there a way to flush my current peers or ban specific peers from my node so I can try to get new ones?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `parity_set` module to manage a reserved peer pool: https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-parity_set-module.

You can call `[parity_dropNonReservedPeers][1]` to get your node to drop all peers. Then add reserved peers with `[parity_addReservedPeer][1]`. Call `[parity_acceptNonReservedPeers][1]` to revert to normal operation.

You may want to take note of the peers that are working well for you, then perform the steps above, adding those good peers to your reserved peers list. You can find your current peer list with https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-parity-module.html#parity_netpeers

Comment: Great idea! Is there a CLI-equivalent for these commands or is it only JSON-RPC?

Comment: Only JSON-RPC AFAIK unfortunately